# Passing an additional value to custom validator in Angular2?

Tags: validation, angular

I have a validator that checks if a users email address is unique, to do this I need to also pass in the users id so that it doesn't include itself in the unique checks. What is the best way to achieve this?

From what I can tell the validator only has access to the control value. I'm hooking up my validator like this:

```
<input #emailAddress="ngForm" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddress" ngControl="emailAddress" required userExists />
```

Currently the only way I've been able to achieve it is by setting a static value on the validator, which is not ideal! Here's my full code for the validator:

```
import { NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, Control } from '@angular/common';
import { Directive, provide, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './user.model';

interface ValidationResult {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[userExists][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        provide(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, {
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => UserExistsValidator),
            multi: true
        })
    ]
})
export class UserExistsValidator {
    public static user: User;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }

    validate(control: Control): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._userService.exists(control.value, UserExistsValidator.user.id).subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    if (response.exists)
                        return resolve({ userExists: { valid: false } });
                    else
                        return resolve(null);
                },
                (error: any) => { console.log(error); }
            )
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a shared service

```ts
@Injectable()
class ValidatorParam {
  value:string; // could also be an observable
}
```

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[userExists][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS, 
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => UserExistsValidator),
            multi: true
        })
    ]
})
export class UserExistsValidator {
    public static user: User;

    constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _param:ValidatorParam) { }

    validate(control: Control): Promise<ValidationResult> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this._param.... // don't know what you want to do with it
            this._userService.exists(control.value, UserExistsValidator.user.id).subscribe(
                (response: any) => {
                    if (response.exists)
                        return resolve({ userExists: { valid: false } });
                    else
                        return resolve(null);
                },
                (error: any) => { console.log(error); }
            )
        });
    }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  providers: [ValidatorParam],
  template: `
<input #emailAddress="ngForm" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.emailAddress" ngControl="emailAddress" required userExists />
`})
 export class MyComponent {
   constructor(private _validatorParam:ValidatorParam) {
     this._validatorParam.value = xxx;
   }
 }
```

This way you can only have one service per component. If you have several input elements in this component, then they need to share the service.

**Caution**: not tried myself.

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it this way than by adding a static variable on the validator to pass the additional value?

Comment: A static variable would modify it for any instance in your application. With a service you can at least limit it to the current component (at least this is what I expect how it will behave)

Comment: @Tucker thanks for the hint. The syntax has changed a bit since then. I updated my answer.